# Error when geom_boxplot used with ggplotly and highlight

Tags: r, highlight, ggplotly

When using geom_boxplot in conjunction with ggplotly and highlight_key I get an error message that reads **All elements of `...` must be named.
Did you want `key = c(key)`?**

For example,  this script produces the error:

```
d <- highlight_key(subset(txhousing, year >= 2012 & !is.na(median)), ~city)
p <- ggplot(d, aes(date, median, group = city)) +  geom_jitter() +  geom_boxplot()
gg <- ggplotly(p, tooltip = "city") 
highlight(gg, dynamic = TRUE)
```

However, this script without boxplot does not:

```
d <- highlight_key(subset(txhousing, year >= 2012 & !is.na(median)), ~city)
p <- ggplot(d, aes(date, median, group = city)) +  geom_jitter() 
gg <- ggplotly(p, tooltip = "city") 
highlight(gg, dynamic = TRUE)
```

A more complex example of this code worked for me a couple of months ago, but does not seem to work currently.  Any ideas what this error means.  I have searched and cannot find documentation on it.

Comment: Have you tried `stat_boxplot(aes(group=city))` instead of `geom_boxplot()`?

Comment: Using stat_boxplot doesn't make a difference.  I get the same error.